# How to make solid torus knot (sverchok nodes)

Tags: modeling, node-editor, procedural, sverchok

I am trying to create a solid torus knot using the sverchok addon. I've started with the following node setup:

[image]

Which produces:

[image]

This works to create edges, but does not work to generate polygons. When switching the UV Connection node to make polygons, I get:

[image]

What I'm going for is two unconnected rings, like a couple of chain links. Like this:

[image]

The key here is being able to use the torus knot node, so I can adjust the torus knot to different configurations, while maintaining the solid structure around it.

Here is the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W8hgo_B8JWy5ZvfJOBlpLgWLUR3aNbo0/view?usp=sharing

Thanks,

Comment: A torus knot is a continuous cyclic path, you can't get two separated torus from it

Comment: on UVconnect turn off slice flag and cycle on two directions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is what you need, maybe. SNL used for sorting.
[image]

import gist:
https://gist.github.com/423c6ca03363c7f4aa2408f8d59df8d4

[image]

Answer (score 2):

chain creation is like that and can be extended with curve modifier:
https://gist.github.com/fccce7bd9fdcd84d20371a72b59e207c
[image]